# Passing parameters between WPF and WCF

Tags: wpf, wcf, list, binding, wcf-binding

I have a self hosting WCF application with a java client. I have a WPF application which imlements the class

```
namespace WcfServiceLibrary6
{
    class Products
    {
        public string ProductID { get; set; }
        public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
        public string RangeOfProducts { get; set; }
        public string ProductDesc { get; set; }
        public string UnitPrice { get; set; }
        public string Discontinued { get; set; }
        public string Image { get; set; }
        //  public Bitmap Bimage = new Bitmap(50, 50);

        public System.Collections.IDictionary AttributeDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }

}
```

The data is stored as a list(the wpf application(C#) accesses a database)

Now I would like to bind this list to a data contract in wcf so it can send the information to the java client. How do I go about it. The rest of the application works perfectly. I just need to assign the list values(wpf: List productList = new List();) to the members of the data contract.

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Runtime.Serialization;
  using System.ServiceModel;
  using System.Text;
  using WpfApplication24;

 namespace WcfServiceLibrary6
 {
// NOTE: If you change the interface name "IService1" here, you must also update the      reference to "IService1" in App.config.
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    Product getChars(int barid);

}

// Use a data contract as illustrated in the sample below to add composite types to service operations

[DataContract]
public class Product
{
    private string m_ProductID;
    private string m_SerialNumber;
    private string m_RangeOfProducts;
    private string m_ProductDesc;
    private int m_UnitPrice;
    private string m_Discontinued;

    [DataMember]
    public string ProductID
    {
        get { return m_ProductID; }
        set { m_ProductID = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string SerialNumber
    {
        get { return m_SerialNumber; }
        set { m_SerialNumber = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string RangeOfProducts
    {
        get { return m_RangeOfProducts; }
        set { m_RangeOfProducts = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string ProductDesc
    {
        get { return m_ProductDesc; }
        set { m_ProductDesc = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public int UnitPrice
    {
        get { return m_UnitPrice; }
        set { m_UnitPrice = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string Discontinued
    {
        get { return m_Discontinued; }
        set { m_Discontinued = value; }
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone who needs help with hosting a wcf service, I found this website very useful :
wcfguidanceforwpf.codeplex.com

Answer (score 0):

Add method with [OnSerializing Attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.onserializingattribute%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

```
    [OnSerializing()]
    public void fun()
    {

    }
```

Where Product properties can be populated from the list.